# ionic Cannot show full month string in picker due to picker option width

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Part of month name string is hidden for long month name in Chinese like 十一月
[image]

**Observation:**
In inspector, altering width(css) of picker option results in full month name shown.
However, the alignment is broken.
[image]

Hope to see advice to correctly show the month name.
Thanks

Comment: Why not increase the width in the css by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enlarge month name datepicker width:
add

```
.picker-col{
    max-width: 70px !important;
}
```

in `app.scss`

Answer (score 1):

try something like this for full months names:

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
 <ion-datetime display-format="DD MMMM YYYY" picker-format="DD/MMMM/YYYY"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that cannot accept this answer as this changes the desired picker format